# Get data from two tables with different columns filtered by a field

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TurbinaGas5](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id_central] [int] NULL,
    [presion_agua_alta] [float] NULL,
    [presion_agua_media] [float] NULL,
    [presion_agua_baja] [float] NULL,
    [temperatura_gases_entrando_tg] [float] NULL,
    [fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Eficiencia_Camara_Combustion] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TurbinaGas5] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TurbinaVapor7](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id_central] [int] NULL,
    [presion_vapor_alta] [float] NULL,
    [presion_vapor_recalentado_caliente] [float] NULL,
    [consumo_auxiliares] [float] NULL,
    [potencia_neta_medida] [float] NULL,
    [eficiencia_termica_bruta] [float] NULL,
    [fecha] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TV7] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

[Database Diagram(sample)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJx6o.png)

These tables are not relationated, altough they don't have the same columns, their data is saved with the same datetime stamp (Fecha field). Now, my problem is that I want to select some fields from both tables filtered by datetime (the date from any table, because it is supposed is the same).

Probably you are asking, why don't you save all the fields in the same table as they are saved at the same timestamp?, this is because every table contains almost 200 fields and they belong to different section in the plant (this project is for a thermo power plant).

Both tables only share the field: id_central as foreign key.

I've tried to build a query like this:

```
select tg5.presion_agua_alta, tv7.flujo_vapor_alta from 
TurbinaGas5 tg5 inner join TurbinaVapor7 tv7 on tg5.id_central=tv7.id_central where tg5.fecha between CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-04-18 01:50:00',102) and CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-04-19 09:41:00',102)
```

but this query returns millions of rows and kills the server. Thank you

For example, let's suppose the tables store the following data:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TurbinaVapor7] ON
INSERT [dbo].[TurbinaVapor7] ([id], [id_central], [presion_vapor_alta], [presion_vapor_recalentado_caliente], [consumo_auxiliares], [potencia_neta_medida], [eficiencia_termica_bruta], [fecha]) VALUES (11983, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, CAST(0x0000A75A0128A180 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TurbinaVapor7] ([id], [id_central], [presion_vapor_alta], [presion_vapor_recalentado_caliente], [consumo_auxiliares], [potencia_neta_medida], [eficiencia_termica_bruta], [fecha]) VALUES (11985, 1, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, CAST(0x0000A75A011826C0 AS DateTime))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TurbinaVapor7] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TurbinaGas5]    Script Date: 04/19/2017 18:29:50 ******/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TurbinaGas5] ON
INSERT [dbo].[TurbinaGas5] ([id], [id_central], [presion_agua_alta], [presion_agua_media], [presion_agua_baja], [temperatura_gases_entrando_tg], [fecha], [Eficiencia_Camara_Combustion]) VALUES (12024, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, CAST(0x0000A75A0128A180 AS DateTime), 5)
INSERT [dbo].[TurbinaGas5] ([id], [id_central], [presion_agua_alta], [presion_agua_media], [presion_agua_baja], [temperatura_gases_entrando_tg], [fecha], [Eficiencia_Camara_Combustion]) VALUES (12029, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, CAST(0x0000A75A01391C40 AS DateTime), 7)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TurbinaGas5] OFF
```

I would like to obtain the cada containend on both tables that is between 2017-04-19 18:00:00.000 and 2017-04-19 19:00:00.000

Hope you can help me, thank you

Comment: Based on your data sample, would you want to limit your record matches to those with the same `[fecha]` value? Without that type of limit, the SELECT you are specifying will match all records for `[id_central]` = 1 in `[TurbinaVapor7]` to every record for `[id_central]` = 1 in `[TurbinaGas5]` within the time range you selected. So, if there were 1000 rows in each of the table, you would retrieve 1000 * 1000 = 1000000 rows total. with 10000 rows in each, you will retrieve 100000000 rows, which will kill most servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need data for each row, whether or not there is a matching row in the other table, you should do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` with `[id_central]` and `[fecha]`. For only rows that have matching `[fecha]` values, use an inner join. Your queries would look something like this, depending on exactly what it is you need:

```
-- All rows with matching fecha

select 
    tg5.presion_agua_alta, 
    tv7.flujo_vapor_alta 
from TurbinaGas5 tg5 
inner join TurbinaVapor7 tv7 
    on tg5.id_central=tv7.id_central
    AND tg5.fecha = tv7.fecha
where tg5.fecha between CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-04-18 01:50:00',102) and CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-04-19 09:41:00',102)


-- All rows from TurbinaGas5, and any with matching fecha in TurbinaVapor7

select 
    tg5.presion_agua_alta, 
    tv7.flujo_vapor_alta 
from TurbinaGas5 tg5 
LEFT join TurbinaVapor7 tv7 
    on tg5.id_central=tv7.id_central
    AND tg5.fecha = tv7.fecha
where tg5.fecha between CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-04-18 01:50:00',102) and CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-04-19 09:41:00',102)


-- All rows in both tables, matching fecha on the same row

select 
    tg5.presion_agua_alta, 
    tv7.flujo_vapor_alta 
from TurbinaGas5 tg5 
FULL OUTER join TurbinaVapor7 tv7 
    on tg5.id_central=tv7.id_central
    AND tg5.fecha = tv7.fecha
where tg5.fecha between CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-04-18 01:50:00',102) and CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-04-19 09:41:00',102)
    or tv7.fecha between CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-04-18 01:50:00',102) and CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-04-19 09:41:00',102)
```

Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the detailed help, The first query will help me, I need all rows only matching date.